# Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath

Tags: spring, validation, email

Today,I am looking into send Email, but when I add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>
```

to pom.xml and deploy on the server, I get an " Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath." validation exception.

I'm just added the dependency above and the one for email to a template MVC project.

Error stacktrace:

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.ui.context.support.UiApplicationContextUtils - Unable to locate ThemeSource with name 'themeSource': using default [org.springframework.ui.context.support.DelegatingThemeSource@20212230]
DEBUG: org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean - Failed to set up a Bean Validation provider
javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:271)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:223)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.java:40)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4944)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: The `javaee` dependencies includes the `javax.validation` packages, which in turn trigger the automatic registration of a `JSR-303` bean validation. But the `javaee` only has the API not an implementation for it. Either add an implementation or don't use the fat `javaee` jar as a dependency. Also it isn't an error it is a debug message, telling you a provider cannot be found, your application should start regardless of that.

Comment: You can also add some starter dependency like `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:SOME_VERSION`. That includes the Hibernate validator.

Answer (score 152):

Add a Bean Validation Provider dependency e.g Hibernate Validator. The Bean Validation API dependency is available on the classpath but the implementation is missing. Add the following to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Note that since 6.0 `groupId` has changed see:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator

Also note that:

- HB Validator 6.x is the last big release that works well with JavaEE (javax).
- HB Validator 7.x targets Jakarta EE 9.
- HB Validator 8.x targets Jakarta EE 10.

Source: https://in.relation.to/2022/08/04/hibernate-validator-705-624-final-800-cr2-released/

Comment: This did the trick, I wonder how this error was presented recently and the project has been under development for more than a year...

Comment: If this answer helped you then please accept the answer.

Comment: @ssostalker probably something changed in the parent pom project which resulted in this error :)

Comment: Hi it says "...a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath." does it mean there's alternative? Cause hibernate validator seems to bring in the whole jboss family...

Comment: is there any alternative to hibernate-validator? it seems to slow down the app startup

Comment: Note: `org.hibernate` artifact location was moved to ``org.hibernate.validator` as per https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator

Comment: Note that if you want to use javax (old package names) you should probably use HB Validator 6.x as 7.x is targeting Jakarta EE (not Java EE).

Answer (score 137):

To resolve the same issue for **Spring Boot** and **Gradle** users add following dependency to your project

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
```

Comment: For mvn users:  Use this <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Comment: This answer helps me after update Spring Boot from 2.2.2.RELEASE to 2.4.2.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, caz i am not using hibernate in my application then why i need to add hibernate validator, i only need to add spring validation

Comment: Siva Anand thank you for the comment. you are right. I'm also agree with you

Answer (score 31):

You can only add one dependency, and resolve the error.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

`org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation` has following dependencies, which are `org.glassfish:jakarta.el`and `org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator`.
Then, `org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator` has `jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api`.

[image]

Comment: This took care of 2 warnings for me. Spring Boot and its libraries are Just sweet. Makes the life of Codes easy. Worked like a Charm

Answer (score 14):

I made it work downgrading the dependency of hibernate-validator from version `7.0.2.Final` to `6.0.13.Final`.

This is how my dependencies look like:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.13.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Excellent! Already spent a day trying to figure out the issue. This solution immediately worked.

Answer (score 12):

In my case, I moved to Hibernate 7.x but had an old explicit dependency on:

```
<dependency>
  <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
  <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
  <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Once I removed this dependency, and allowed Hibernate to transitively pull in the dependency to the Jakarta Bean Validation API (jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:3.0.0). Everything worked fine.

Answer (score 7):

You need to add any validation provider dependency for example Hibernate Validator.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hibernate validator group id has been changed from version 6.x.x and an exmaple is given below,  
    `<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>  
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>  
    <version>6.1.7.Final</version>  
    </dependency>`

Answer (score 7):

If you are using spring-boot-starter dependencies, then prefer adding another one for validation.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

Hibernate Validator requires an implementation of [Jakarta Expression Language](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.el) for evaluating dynamic expressions in constraint violation messages.

When your application runs in a Java EE container such as JBoss Application Server, an EL implementation is already provided by the container.

In a Java SE environment, however, you have to add an implementation as dependency to your POM or gradle file.

For instance you can add the following dependency to use the Jakarta EL reference implementation:

**maven**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.el</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

or **gradle**

```
implementation 'org.glassfish:jakarta.el:4.0.2'
```

[Hibernate validator documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-gettingstarted-createproject)

If you are using spring-boot-starter-validation in your project, hibernate-validator and jakarta.el are already in the dependencies of the given starter.

[spring-boot-starter-validation](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/2.3.1.RELEASE/jar)

Answer (score 3):

Springboot 3 has significantly simplified our lives. With the addition of just two dependencies, we are ready to go... alternatively this [video](https://youtu.be/0Y-V78_XcrY) might be helpful

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

on Jun 2022, it should helps:

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
...
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.el/jakarta.el-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.el</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator-annotation-processor -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
```

imports in class:

```
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Email;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just need to add the following dependencies to your POM.XML
In my case, Spring-boot v3, Java 17

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.expressly</groupId>
        <artifactId>expressly</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

See the following documentation for more details - [Jboss Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-gettingstarted-createproject)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an incompatibility with Guice and/or Reactor.io in some of the versions. This worked for me in a Spring Boot WebFlux solution:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.el</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import lombok.Data;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class ValidationTests {

    @Test
    public void validate(){
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setName("7of9");
        assertThat(validator.validate(foo).size()).isNotZero();
    }

    @Data
    class Foo{

        @Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z]", message = "Only letters allowed")
        private String name;

    }
}
```

Otherwise I'd be getting the same error as reported or getting build errors (Guice would become excluded from classpath.

Answer (score 0):

In my case helped to add the next dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error when I migrate a spring boot 2.6 service to the version 3.0.1. Adding the hibernate validator and the other libs that refer in this post.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.6.0'
        groovyVersion = '3.0.13'
        groovySpockVersion = '2.4-M1-groovy-3.0'        
        springBootVersion = '3.0.1'
        springSecurityVersion = '2.6.8'
        springDocVersion = '1.5.12'
        hibernateValidatorVersion = '8.0.0.Final'
        javaxElApiVersion = '3.0.0'
        javaxElVersion = '2.0.1.Final'
        javaxElImplVersion = '2.2.6'        
...
    }
...
    implementation("javax.el:javax.el-api:${javaxElApiVersion}")
    implementation("javax.validation:validation-api:${javaxElVersion}")
    implementation("org.glassfish.web:javax.el:${javaxElImplVersion}")
    implementation("org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:${hibernateValidatorVersion}")
    implementation("org.hibernate:hibernate-validator-annotation-processor:${hibernateValidatorVersion}")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error is because I m using spring boot version 3.0.1 and hibernate-validator version 6.2.0 which is incompatible. By upgrading hibernate-validator to 7.0.1.Final the problem was resolved

```
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but latter on i resolve this one by adding following dependency im **pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Facing same issue in SpringBoot, Gradle project. I was getting below exception

```
Unable to create a Configuration, because no Jakarta Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
```

The exception was happening because of `@Validated` on my ConfigProperties class.

```
  @Data
    @Validated
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my-service")
    public class FConfigProperties {
      private String apiBase;
      private OAuthCredentials oAuthCredentials;

    
    @NoArgsConstructor
      @AllArgsConstructor
      @Data
      public static class OAuthCredentials {
    
        private String username;
        private String password;
      }
}
```

Root cause: The Validator provider was missing as the required dependency was not provided in `build.gradle`

**Solution** Add below dependency in build.gradle.

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case I didn't need Validators so removing them also removes the error without needing the hibernate-validator dependencies. Regular tests run fine.

```
public class Test 
{

    public  ObjectMapper mapper;
    public  Validator validator;                //remove
    public  ValidatorFactory validatorFactory;  //remove

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();  //remove
        validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();                   //remove
    }
  ...
}
```