# SpringBoot No ConfigurationProperties annotation found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am getting the following error while trying to execute this code.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No ConfigurationProperties annotation found on  'com.app.AggregatorAppAConfiguration'.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115) ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationPropertiesImportSelector$ConfigurationPropertiesBeanRegistrar.registerBeanDefinition(EnableConfigurationPropertiesImportSelector.java:117) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]

Wondering what is done wrong here

```
   @Component
public class AggregatorApp 
{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AggregatorApp.class);

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {


        logger.info("good");
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(AggregatorAppAConfiguration.class);
        app.setWebEnvironment(false);

        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = app.run(args);

        ctx.getBean(AggregatorApp.class).run();

    }

    public void run() {
        aggManager.start();
        System.out.println("Hello World !!");
    }
}



@Service
public class AggregatorManager {

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}


@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.app.aggregator")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AggregatorAppAConfiguration.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class AggregatorAppAConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public AggregatorManager aggregatorManager()
    {
        return new AggregatorManager();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you explicitly pointed `@EnableConfigurationProperties` at it.

Comment: It does not seem to resolve my issue

Comment: @SMA The way it's written is fine if a bit odd.

Comment: @chrylis . Removing Enableconfigurationproperties resolved my issue. But now I am getting the following error  "***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
The Bean Validation API is on the classpath but no implementation could be found"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@chrylis . Thanks the issue is fixed by removing @SpringBootApplication and 
[Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329001/unable-to-create-a-configuration-because-no-bean-validation-provider-could-be-f)