# Getting javax.validation.NoProviderFoundException exception even after adding the dependencies

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I am new to Java and maven. I might be missing something obvious, but I am not able to figure it out.

I was trying to add javax validations to my project following the link :
https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation

And I have added the following dependencies

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.13.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
```

I have tried group ids org.hibernate and org.hibernate.validator also.

But I was getting a runtime error during the execution of buildDefaultValidatorFactory() of:

```
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
```

I was getting the following error

```
Method threw 'javax.validation.NoProviderFoundException' exception.
Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
```

What am I missing? Let me know if you need some key info. I have been fighting with this for hours. So, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the hibernate and glassfish validation. Just keep javax one. Clean your project properly.

Then right do project->runas->maven build ->clean install once.

At the same time you can update your project also click on project ->maven>update project

Comment: I just had javax only. But when I had to use the validator(Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();). I added hibernate(following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329001/unable-to-create-a-configuration-because-no-bean-validation-provider-could-be-f). But still getting the error.