# javax.validation.NoProviderFoundException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, maven

no Hibernate Bean Validator could be found even though it's added to the classpath.

I have a simple web application in Spring Boot. I am trying to test the Hibernate Validator with this simple function:

```java
public void validateUser(User user) {
   ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
   Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
   Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> violations = validator.validate(user);
}
```

But it throws an exception:
**javax.validation.NoProviderFoundException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.**

I tried using different libraries but they all don't work.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I am using Java 17.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66348372/11002 may help

Comment: Cannot reproduce. It should require only `spring-boot-starter-validation`.

Answer (score 1):

For a Spring Boot project you would want to add the `spring-boot-starter-validation` starter dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

All the Spring Boot started projects can be found in the official documentation: [spring.io](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.build-systems.starters)

After you add a new dependency to your `pom.xml` file, I recommend running `mwnv clean package` (or `mvn clean package`) to fetch the dependencies and build a clean project.

Also, for bootstrapping/generating Spring Boot projects you may want to use [***Spring Initializr***](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.5.7&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=web,validation).